# keycloak connect backend systems with oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I would like to secure our web services and would like to know if I have understand the concept and how to implement this in keycloak. We have 2 backend systems A and B and keycloak as oauth2 provider. System A consumes services on system B.

1. I would like to let system A requests an access token from keycloack with client credentials flow, because this is an backend request only.
2. System A sends the request to system B along with this access token
3. System B checks the access token against keycloak
4. System B sends actual service response if token check has passed or an appropriate failure message.

Is that a good approach and how can we implemnt this in keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

You have three types of access types with keycloak

1. public
2. confidential
3. bearer-only

More information can be found here

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html

If Your System A is accessed by other client facing UI then implement System A and System B as bearer-only clients.